# How to install Debian with encrypted / and passphrase required before login-screen?

Tags: installation, encryption, login-screen, debian

I'm trying to install Debian in my Dell inspiron 8GB ram + 500GB HD. Althought I could install it without any problems with the regular install and even with a few modifications, I'm trying to maximize my computers security, and therefore I would like to have the / folder encrypted.

Not only that, I would also like that the passphrase for it's encryption was asked before the login screen loaded. The computer will have only one user, and root permissions run trough sudo. So, the question is:

How do I get to install Debian with a passphrase for encrypted / asked before the login screen?

This is my initial ideia to assure security, but I'm open to new ideas and other devices I can use for that purpose.

Thank you very much,

Ju

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is off topic and should probably go to unix.stackexchange.com instead.

That said, the setup for encrypted root is the same as with any other encrypted partition. One thing you have to keep in mind though: You need to make a separate /boot partition, which must not be encrypted.

As always with questions regarding the installation of Debian, I refer to the really excellent documentation of Debian. The chapters relevant to you are:

http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s03.html.en#di-partition

http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch07s02.html.en